# WooCommerce Single product image hover Zoom blinking

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I install the WooCommerce additional variation Image on my website and I lose hove zooming however I found one solution for that and added below code in function.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_setup' );

function yourtheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

And hover zoom is working good only for one selected image once I changed to different then I am getting unexpected zooming like bliking.

If anyone has any solution please do help me.
here is product link: https://www.fitspare.com/product/dymatize-elite-100-whey-protein-5-lbs/

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I faced the same issue today and did not find any help anywhere, so I thought this could help someone.

I tried disabling all plugins and the issue persisted. Then I changed the theme and the zoom/magnification was working correctly. Since I am using a child theme I first disabled the child theme to see if the issue is within the child or parent theme and found out that the parent theme was conflicting with woocommerce zoom functionality.

I have tried dequeuing all the javascript and css files one by one until I found the style that was causing the issue. Eventually I noticed that the parent theme had the below styling:

```css
img {
    opacity:1;-webkit-transition:opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition:opacity .5s ease;
    transition:opacity .5s ease
}
```

In my child theme I overwrote that styling by including the below in my child theme stylesheet:

##### Option 1

I added the `body` in front of `img` to be more specific and avoid the `!important`
but this will disable transition on all images:

```css
body img { 
    transition: none;
}
```

#### Option 2

this will only disable transition on images with class `zoomImg`

```css
img.zoomImg {
    transition: none;
}
```